# How to send csv file as attachment in android?

Tags: android

Hi i am developing an android application with email functionality. Here i need to send a CSV file from my path data/data/mypackage/files folder. I am storing the csv file there.It is saving there good.My csv file size is just 245 bytes only. But when i  tried to send that file throught mail  functionality of android is displaying "File too Large to attach.." message is displaying.

Here is my code:

```
String filelocation="file:///data/data/my package/files/excerDB.zip";   
            final Intent emailIntent = new 

    Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);           
                emailIntent .setType("plain/text");             
                emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"purpletalk.raghu@gmail.com"});             
                emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attendence Report");             
                emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filelocation));


            startActivity( emailIntent);
```

But it is not working for me. Please advice me how can i send my file as a attachment to mail in my application.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this code will help u

```
String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
            + "Foldername";
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        // sendIntent.setType("text/html");
        sendIntent.setType("application/csv");
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
        String temp_path = FILE + "/" + "Filename.csv";
        File F = new File(temp_path);
        Uri U = Uri.fromFile(F);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Mail"));
```

Enjoy this code!

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my application i dont want to use Sdcard. So i want to deal with local data/data/package/files/myfile.csv path. Can i change the above code to send file from my path?

Comment: private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/Packagename";
 private static String DB_NAME = "Filename.csv";                                   String myPath = DB_PATH + "/" + DB_NAME; File F = new File(temp_path);
        Uri U = Uri.fromFile(F); use this code i hope this code will help u

Comment: Sorry same problem "File too large to attach"

Comment: The reason why it could be stuck in the sending state is because depending on the **SIZE** of the zip file, it has to add it to the email.. If its too large (over 30 MB) it might hang and get denied by google, since google does not allow the sending of over 30MB in an email. This is just a guess, but try sending a small file and see if this is the case.

Comment: My file size is 220.0 KB only.

Comment: i don't understand why this problem come in Your application. same thing i have do it successfully sending .

Comment: i am running the application in emulator. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: yes i have face some problem .. t thing u should try this code on device

Comment: @AkashSingh how can get all contacts into file

Comment: Correct mime type for csv is `text/csv` (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7111) and not `application/csv`.